# remove directory name from linux find result

Tags: linux, find

when I using find command with below

```
find /asdf/asset -mtime -3 -printf "%f " > log.txt
```

result is below

```
asset text.txt movie.ts
```

asset is not exist, it's a directory. how to hide directory name from result.

Comment: Add `-type f` to list only files.

Comment: `find /asdf/asset -type f -mtime -3 -printf "%f " > log.txt`